# Find and mark first occurance of the element

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a list of elements in A column and I want to find the first occurence of each element and mark it "YES" in B column, like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Yes |
| Cheese | Yes |
| Bread | Yes |
| Cheese | No |
| Cheese | No |
| Bread | No |
| Pineapple | Yes |

How can I do this in VBA?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to do this in VBA? a formula (`=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,"Yes","No")` would do the trick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad thanks, it helped!

Comment: Alternative: Using the newer dynamic array features you might enter a single formula into `B2` to get a spill range: `=IF(MATCH(A2:A8,A2:A8,0)=ROW(A2:A8)-1,"Yes","No")` (where `-1` is used to synchronize the row count as data start in the 2nd row only. If to no success you might also try entering it as a {formula array} via <kbd>**C*trl</kbd>>kbd>**S*hift</kbd><kbd>**E*nter</kbd> @mitya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flag First Occurrences (VBA Formula)

**Excel Formula**

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1,"Yes","No")
```

**Compact**

```vb
Sub FlagFirstOccurrencesCompact()
    
    Const SourceFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const DestinationColumn As String = "B"
    Const YesFlag As String = "Yes"
    Const NoFlag As String = "No"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    With ws.Range(SourceFirstCellAddress)
        Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow < .Row Then Exit Sub
        Dim Formula As String
        Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & .Address(, 0) & ":" & .Address(0, 0) & "," _
            & .Address(0, 0) & ")=1,""" & YesFlag & """,""" & NoFlag & """)"
        With .Resize(lRow - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Columns(DestinationColumn)
            .Formula = Formula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Argumented**

```vb
Sub FlagFirstOccurrencesTEST()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    FlagFirstOccurrences ws.Range("A2"), "B", "Yep", "Nope"
End Sub

Sub FlagFirstOccurrences( _
        ByVal SourceFirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal FlagColumn As String, _
        Optional ByVal YesFlag As String = "Yes", _
        Optional ByVal NoFlag As String = "No")
    
    With SourceFirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = .Worksheet.Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow < .Row Then Exit Sub
        Dim Formula As String
        Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(" & .Address(, 0) & ":" & .Address(0, 0) & "," _
            & .Address(0, 0) & ")=1,""" & YesFlag & """,""" & NoFlag & """)"
        With .Resize(lRow - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Columns(FlagColumn)
            .Formula = Formula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried them, both worked perfectly, and have step through each of the codes to understand, very neat steps!